# ¿Como exportar un arreglo de objetos a un archivo .csv sin tener que generar una tabla en html react.js? | Ocupo npm react-export-excel

Tags: reactjs, csv, exportar

Tengo que imprimir un archivo csv, obtengo un arreglo de arreglos en el cual por cada iteración quiero ejecutar las etiquetas para poder exportar el excel de cada array, la problematica es que como puedo hacer una exportación sin necesidad de crear el botón en html(que se haga la descarga de forma automatica por cada item(un array) de mi arreglo de arreglos)

```
    return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    {ordersforshops.length > 0 ? (
      ordersforshops.map((item, key) => (
         <ExcelFile element={<button>Exportar</button>} filename="StatusAccount">
    <ExcelSheet data={item} name="StatusAccount">
      <ExcelColumn label="ID" value="id" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Fecha" value="Fecha" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Hora" value="Hora" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Forma de Pago" value="Formadepago" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Importe de Venta" value="Importventa" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Descuento de cliente" value="Descuentocl" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Monedero Electronico" value="MCC" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Sub Total" value="Subtotal" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Comisión Niku" value="ComisionNk" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Subtotal sin IVA" value="Subsiniva" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Retención 8%" value="IVA8" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Retención ISR 1%" value="ISR1" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Comisión de envio" value="Comsend" />
      <ExcelColumn label="Total" value="TotalADepositarporOrden" />
    </ExcelSheet>
  </ExcelFile>
      ))
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h2>NO HUBO DATOS</h2>
      </div>
    )}
    <AmplifySignOut />
    {listTags.length > 0 ? (
      listTags.map((item, key) => (
        <p key={key}>{item.address_id.outdoor_number}</p>
      ))
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h2>Cargando..</h2>
      </div>
    )}
  </header>
</div>
```

);

Comment: Falta mucho contexto. De donde viene la data que quieres exportar? Puedes incluir el componente completo? Quieres que la descarga se inicie inmediatamente después de que se monte el componente en cuestión?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en [esta pregunta,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server) puedes crear el texto del csv en memoria y luego gatillar la descarga usando HTML5 puro de esta manera:

```javascript
const download = (csvString, fileName = 'test.csv') => {
    // Creamos el elemento para hacer el trigger del download
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString));
    element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);  
}
```

Sólo falta crear el string del csv:

```javascript
// Suponiendo tenemos los datos como listas
const headers = ['foo', 'bar']
const rows = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

// Creamos el csv en texto plano
const csvString = headers.join(',') + '\n' + rows.map(row => row.join(',')).join('\n');
// Descargamos
download(csvString, 'number.csv')

// Si las filas son objetos
const rowsObject = [{'foo':1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo':3, 'bar': 4}]
const csvStringObject = headers.join(',') + '\n' + rows.map(row => Object.values(row).join(',')).join('\n');
// Ojo que Object.values() funciona si los objetos tienen los atributos en el mismo orden que la lista de 'headers'.
// const rowsObject = [{'foo':1, 'bar': 2}, {'bar': 4, 'foo':3}] // mal codificado
// Descargamos
download(csvStringObject, 'object.csv')
```

Esto lo puedes poner tanto en `onClick` de botones como en un `useEffect` para ejectuarlo al montar el componente

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡FUNCIONA!